# LINQ запрос, как узнать что все элементы колекции одинаковы?

Tags: запрос, linq

LINQ запрос, как узнать что все элементы колекции одинаковы?

Comment: Вам надо сравнить 2 коллекции на одинаковость? Так и пишите в вопросе тогда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx) же

```
ProductA[] storeA = { new ProductA { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                       new ProductA { Name = "orange", Code = 4 } };

ProductA[] storeB = { new ProductA { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                       new ProductA { Name = "orange", Code = 4 } };

bool equalAB = storeA.SequenceEqual(storeB);
```

Answer (score 1):

Смотря что вы понимаете под одинаковостью и какие типы сравниваете, например так можно.

```
if (myCol.Distinct().Count() == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Неэффективно, но кратко:

```
if (a.All(x => x == a.First()))
```

Если вынести в переменную, будет несколько лучше:

```
var first = a.First();
if (a.All(x => x == first))
```